# Hibernate SQL Error Column not found

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

The FIELD_5 is primary key in TABLE_1 and not a foreign in TABLE_2. Its showing FIELD_5 column not found.

Have used Hibernate XML for mapping. FIELD_5 is mapped into XML
Caused by: `java.sql.SQLException: Column 'FIELD_5'` not found.

```
select 
    inv.Field_ID,c.FIELD_7 as FIELD_7,s.FIELD_3,sum(inv.FIELD_4) as FIELD_4
from
    (SELECT 
        m.Field_ID, t.FIELD_1,t.FIELD_2, t.AMOUNT as FIELD_4
    FROM
        TABLE_1 m
    INNER JOIN TABLE_2 t ON m.FIELD_5 = t.FIELD_5
    Where
        m.FIELD_6 = 'PURCHASE' AND m.Field_ID=2
            and m.FIELD_7 = 'S' and t.TFIELD_8 != 'F'
            AND t.CREATED_DATE BETWEEN '2016-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-03-31 00:00:00'
           ) as inv
   INNER JOIN 
(select distinct FIELD_3,FIELD_2 from TABLE_4 ) as s
ON inv.FIELD_2=s.FIELD_2 
INNER JOIN TABLE_3 c on inv.Field_ID=c.Field_ID
where s.FIELD_3 in (400019,400004,400012)
group by   inv.Field_ID,s.FIELD_3;
```

And i have added in TABLE_2 Entity
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FIELD_5")
    private String field5;

How do I generate SQL query using this SQL query

SCHEME FOR TABLES

```
CREATE TABLE `TABLE_2` (
  `FIELD_5` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `FIELD_1` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `FIELD_2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `FIELD_6` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `FIELD_8` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATED_BY` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `MODIFIED_BY` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MODIFIED_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ORDER_ID`,`SCHEME_REF_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `TABLE_1` (
  `FIELD_5` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Field_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `FIELD_6` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `FIELD_7` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATED_BY` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `MODIFIED_BY` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MODIFIED_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MW_REQUEST_PRN`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `TABLE_3` (
  `FIELD_1` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Field_2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `FIELD_3` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_BY` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `MODIFIED_BY` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MODIFIED_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FIELD_1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `TABLE_1` (
  `FIELD_1` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `FIELD_3` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `FIELD_2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_BY` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `MODIFIED_BY` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MODIFIED_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FIELD_1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Is table contains `FIELD_5` column?

Comment: Yes. And i have used Hibernate XML for mapping. The query works fine in mysql .

Comment: Please post the schema of your tables otherwise we can only guess what is going wrong

Comment: @Zelldon did you able to crack this

Comment: Why do you have two create tables for Table1?